# console.table does not show Observer

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

code:

```
console.log(this.data)
```

If the parameter of console.table is `Observer`, the console output is an ellipsis

How do I get him to output the final value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.dir(this.data)` to output a browse-able object you can click through.

You will also likely get better results if you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data))`

Comment: console.table(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))) , This can be written, but the performance may not be high